# Solving $x! = x^2$ (or $\Gamma(x) = x)$

Tags: functions

I want to solve $x^{2x!} = (x!)^{x^2}$.

Aside for $1$ and $2$, the solution is $x! = x^2$.

When dividing by $x$, we get $\Gamma(x) = x$.

I don't know how to continue from that. I tried replacing $\Gamma(x)$ by its integral form, but I'm not able to solve it.

Edit: I already plotted the equations even before I tried solving, and I know the result is about 3.55. I just want to know where it comes from. I am not interested in the value, but in the equation and the way to solve it.

Comment: ChrisRahme:  You're obviously new here, and are still struggling to use basic *MathJax*.  There are a number of tutorials that can help:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Given the use of $x!$ assume you are searching for integer solutions. Try plotting $y = x^2$ and $y = x!$ on Desmos, and you'll see that the only integer solution to $x^2 = x!$ is $x = 1$.

Comment: $1!=1^2$
$2! \leq 2^2$
$3!\ leq 3^2$
$4!\geq4^2$
$n! \geq n^2$ for $n \geq 4$.

Comment: David G. Stork: Yes I am. I read the MathJax tutorial but it was showing in the preview as if it was regular text.

Comment: @jmacmanus, as I also wrote about the gamma function, I am interested in real numbers. I know 1 and 2 are the only integer solutions. And I tried plotting in GeoGebra. I know the result is about 3.55.

Comment: $2$ isn't a solution. $2^2\ne 2!$ As a computer science student, you should show interest for LaTex, shouldn' t you? 

Comment: @ChrisRahmé Yes, numerically it is $\approx 3.5623822853908976914156443427476103118$

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya, 2 is a solution of the original equation I wanted to solve. And yeah, as a software engineering student and maths lover I am interested in LaTex! Sadly they don't teach this kind of interesting stuff in university.

Answer (score 1):

This plot may help, where the two functions cross twice:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the equation, there is a trivial root $x=1$.

For the other one, by inspection, you know that the solution is between $x=3$ and $x=4$ and Newton method would converge very fast; being myself quite lazy, I shall start with $x_0=3.5$ and get the following iterates  shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 3.5000000 \\
 1 & 3.5662556 \\
 2 & 3.5623964 \\
 3 & 3.5623823
\end{array}
\right)$$